# SendBird Push only one notification - android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, sendbird

I'm building a chat app android I know well it works only when devices are offline ( in the background )

I've some questions:
1- if a user sends a message to another, **SendBird** push notification for the first message only, and next messages no notifications are sent.

it won't send another notification even the receiver has canceled the notification ( by swipe )
the only way to get notifications again is by asking the receiver to open chat again.

2- also, is there any assistance from the backend dev so push all notifications whether app in the background or foreground?

3- can backend dev assist in sending multiple notifications?

I hope if anyone can assist me with some proof from docs regarding the three points as my PM doesn't believe that SDK has some limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have repo or some sample code for the message send and receive?

Triggering push notifications in Sendbird are passed to Firebase(FCM) or Hauwei(HMS), do you know if message throttling is disabled?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#throttling-and-scaling

**Update**

Oh, see Sendbird's community at https://community.sendbird.com/t/sendbird-push-only-one-notification-android/1017/2